# show custom options in admin

Tags: php, magento

I cannot seem to get the custom options field to display in my magento code below - can any of you good people help me out?

```
public function getProductName($product)
{
    $value = '<b>'.$product->getname().'</b>';
    if ($product->getproduct_type() == 'configurable')
    {
        //add sub products
        $collection = mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                            ->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id', $product->getitem_id());
        foreach ($collection as $subProduct)
        {
            $value .= '<br><i>'.$subProduct->getname().'</i>';

            //add product configurable attributes values
            $attributesDescription = mage::helper('ProductReturn/Configurable')->getDescription($subProduct->getproduct_id(), $product->getrp_product_id());
            if ($attributesDescription != '')
                $value .= '<br>'.$attributesDescription;
        }

    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, If $product is your productId then try below code : 
$_product = $product;
echo $_product->getCustomOptionName();

getCustomOptionName e.g for auction_type -> getAuction_type();

Comment: Thanks Jaydeep - I would assume the custom option would be listed as normal in magento? Which line would I put this code as there are a 2 $product attributes mentioned.

Comment: are you talking about your code or mine?

Comment: There are 2 x $product attributes in the original code

Answer (score 0):

There are issue in $product->getproduct_type() is not wrong it should try it `$product->getTypeId()`

Comment: Thanks Amit - not working for me unfortunately thought getItemOptions would be it but no luck :-( Any other ideas?